# Java: Using a method to get values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to use a method inside of a class to get values from an ArrayList that is inside the main area.

I have searched high and low for answers and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

I need the ArrayList "objectList" to be run through the minArea function. I just don't know how to reference the values within the ArrayList from the minArea/maxArea function. I can surely figure out how to do the actual functions on my own, but I just need to know how to reference the Circle and Square objects within ...

```
public static class geometricObject {
    String color = "white";
    public String fillColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double minArea() {
        return 0;
    }

    public double maxArea() {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static class Circle extends geometricObject {
    public static double radius;
    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        double ans = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
        return ans;
    }
}

public static class Square extends geometricObject {
    public double width;        
    public Square(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        double ans = width * width;
        return ans;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<geometricObject> objectList = new ArrayList<geometricObject>();
    objectList.add(new Circle(8));
    objectList.add(new Circle(3));
    objectList.add(new Square(5));
    objectList.add(new Square(4));
    objectList.add(new Square(3));
    int i = 5;
    System.out.println(objectList..minArea());
}
```

Comment: `objectList..minArea()` is wrong, you should be using `objectList.get(0).minArea()` for example. Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Comment: From the names of your methods (`minArea`, `maxArea`) and your question I'm guessing you actually want to find the minimum or maximum area of all `GeometricObjects` in the collection.  If so, your base class should declare a `getArea` method and entirely separate functions or helper class should implement `public double getMinArea(List<GeometricObject> list);` and `public double getMaxArea(List<GeometricObject> list);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
ArrayList<geometricObject> objectList;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    objectList = new ArrayList<geometricObject>();
    objectList.add(new Circle(8));
    objectList.add(new Circle(3));
    objectList.add(new Square(5));
    objectList.add(new Square(4));
    objectList.add(new Square(3));
    int i = 5;
    System.out.println(objectList..minArea());

}
```

What I did: I put the undefined variable before the method is called, and declared it in the main. In your case however, you may want to put the undefined variable:

```
ArrayList<geometricObject> objectList;
```

Before all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    geomtericObject g = objectList.get(i);
    System.out.println(g.minArea());
    System.out.println(g.getArea());
}
```

or get away from using indexes:

```
foreach (geomtericObject g : objectList) {
    System.out.println(g.minArea());
    System.out.println(g.getArea());
}
```